# What is Games in man page

Tags: linux, man

I'm walking through the manual of man-page. I don't understand the importance of the 6th section Games in Man-pages. What it's really mean?.
[image]

Comment: Yes, games are in the sixth section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The section of the manuals that is dedicated to games contains information about games and toy-like programs.  These are distinct from utilities listed in the first section and administrational tools that live in the 8th section in that they are not considered important for the use and maintenance of the system.  Hence the separate section for them.

Most of these "games" would be command line, character-based, applications.

You may list the manuals in this section on Linux using

```
man -s 6 --regex -k '.*'
```

That is, "show the title of all manuals in section 6".

---

The following is explicitly about "games" on OpenBSD, although some of these games and toy-like utilities may also be packaged for Linux.

Just `ls` on the appropriate directory:

```
$ ls /usr/share/man/man6
adventure.6   bcd.6         factor.6      hangman.6     morse.6       quiz.6        tetris.6
arithmetic.6  boggle.6      fish.6        hunt.6        number.6      rain.6        trek.6
atc.6         bs.6          fortune.6     huntd.6       phantasia.6   random.6      worm.6
backgammon.6  caesar.6      gomoku.6      intro.6       pig.6         robots.6      worms.6
banner.6      canfield.6    grdc.6        mille.6       pom.6         sail.6        wump.6
battlestar.6  cribbage.6    hack.6        monop.6       ppt.6         snake.6
```

It's interesting to note that some of these BSD "games" could actually be considered *useful*, such as `factor` which factors a number into prime factors, and `primes` which generates prime numbers.  Also `banner` is used on some systems to generate (very) basic banners.

The `number` tool could also be considered useful under some circumstances:

```
$ /usr/games/number 23
twenty-three.
```

Answer (score 2):

The games section of the manual, is where the games are documented.

Games are programs used for entertainment. Examples include chess, mine sweeper, tetris, card games, hex-a-hop,